# Is there any tool to add html properties for test automation purposes?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, continuous-integration, automated-tests

Does anybody know if there's a tool that would add html properties to the elements in the DOM tree to make selecting elements easy for automation testing with Selenium?

The tool would need to add a new property so that it wouldn't interfere with existent javascript, for example "data-nav-id" the value of that property could be a hash, something unique, like: data-nav-id="XjsaAksah2ma4".

Another thing is that it shouldn't change the id's that are already there, let's say I add a new div tag to the page, the tool would only insert the property in the new element.

It would be perfect if there was a way add that tool as step for continuous integration in Jenkins.

Comment: I don't know any such tool. But it looks to me like you are looking for a tool that will temporarily inject ids on to the all elements on page just before running your UI automation tests. Even if you found a such a tool, I am curious to know how will you use the ids generated by the tool in your tests?

Comment: @LINGS It could be permanent. I currently don't see an issue to leave the guidance ids there.

Comment: The "tool" you are looking for is the devs that work on your website. Document the elements that you would like to have IDs and submit that list to dev to be added.

Comment: Hey @JeffC this is the problem. This would require me to ask the dev teams to do extra work, and that would not be a very popular request given the project's schedule. The technical debt of those not-automation-friendly pages would require an effort the that the dev teams cannot afford right now. My idea was to solve this without impacting their work, adding a step into continuous integration. I'm considering writing my own tool.

Comment: I don't know how you are going to create a tool that locates elements and adds IDs if you can't just locate the same elements using Selenium.

Comment: Hello @JeffC, the tool is not supposed to query for a specific element,  just to crawl over all htmls of the web application and insert unique ids to every element that don't have an id already. We could then use those ids whenever we need to automate a test case inspecting them with browser debug tool and hard codding those at test automation project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just written a small piece of code that would inject an unique id to each tag in a html file given it's path. I just need to make this run on every html or dynamic front end file like .jsp of every sub-directory of my WEB-INF directory for example or anywhere the front end related files are that depends on the web application framework you're using.

```
package org.automation.htmlcompass;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.select.NodeVisitor;

public class HtmlCompass {

    public static void parseDocument(String path, String outputFile) throws IOException {
        File input = new File(path);
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

        doc.traverse(new NodeVisitor() {

            public void tail(Node node, int depth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void head(Node node, int depth) {
                if (node instanceof Element) {
                    Element e = (Element) node;

                    if(!e.hasAttr("data-nav-id")) {
                        System.out.println("injecting >> tag name "+ e.tagName() + " depth " + depth);
                        injectHash(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        BufferedWriter htmlWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(outputFile), "UTF-8"));
        htmlWriter.write(doc.toString());
        htmlWriter.close();
    }

    private static void injectHash(Element element) {
        String seed = element.toString() + System.currentTimeMillis();
        String hash = DigestUtils.sha512Hex(seed).substring(0, 20);
        element.attr("data-nav-id", hash);
    }
}
```